# how setup shoutcast player without flash (alternative flash player)

Tags: flash, shoutcast

i am currently understand that Flash is dead, i have a radio website now my radio don't work, what is the best tool i can use for add player on my website, tool not under flash because flash is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can use any HTML5 player for your stream, like jPlayer or Soundmanager 2. They also have Flash fallback.